# jQuery UI Draggable: Mouse moves faster than draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

As the title describes, when I move the mouse the mouse moves faster than the div, while I expect the div to stay below my mouse cursor while moving. I am using jQuery UI 1.12.1 and jQuery 3.3.1. I used the default options with the function.

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function()
{
    $(".popup").draggable();
});
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. If you could please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to your post it'll make it easier for someone to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ltd9938 Added some code

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! if there is such type of problem .The position of the mouse cursor relative to the **active element**. The cursor moves to the **center** of the element immediately after the user begins to drag.
By doing so your problem get solved  and the mouse cursor is struck to the centre of active div . till you leave the mouse cursor..
Here is the code of  what i am saying above .....

```js
<!-- Javascript and Jquery-->

$('div').on('mousedown', function (e) {

    $(this).addClass('active').parents().on('mousemove', function (e) {

        $('.active').offset({

            top: e.pageY - $('.active').outerHeight() / 2,
            left: e.pageX - $('.active').outerWidth() / 2

        }).on('mouseup', function () {

            $(this).removeClass('active');

        });
        
    });
    
    return false;    
});
```

```css
div {
    cursor: move;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:black;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
}
.active {
    background: grey;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```